# How to check the memory leak from the given retained path which contains webviewNode in the Electron app

Tags: memory-leaks, electron, heap-dump

[image]

> this heap snapshot was created by a renderer process in the Electron app

Electron version:v16

**that 'o' is a vuecompnent;**

**the v8eventListenter is most likely a 'mouseenter-event-listener' on the div;**

**the div is supposed to be collected by GC;**

all detached elements point to the webviewNode, but I believe it's not its problem.

Can anyone provide me with a direction to find out what the problem is?

Comment: it is a remedy that is to remove the webview node by "webview.parentElement.removeChild(webview)" to avoid the expansion of memory leak，it seems work